# Simple cropping with lwjgl/opengl

Tags: opengl, crop, lwjgl

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX04r.png <-- example image

How might I crop some quads before drawing them to the screen? What I have right now looks like the leftmost image. I'd like it to look like the rightmost one. I found some information on masking with lwjgl/opengl, but I think it should be simpler since these are just rectangular croppings.

Answer (score 0):

Using a stencil mask is the easiest option. Changing the vertex buffer on CPU (manual crop) is more complicated but may be faster.